# Time complexity for different input sizes

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am a computer science freshman and on my book, there is a table with the time taken to compute an algorithm according to the input size. How comes those values are fixed? I thought it will also depends on the machine where the operations are performed. For example a 1990 computer is not even close to a 2018 computer in terms of efficiency. I am a bit confused.

[Growth rates for different input sizes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4297.png)

Comment: From the picture you put as link: "This data assumes that a single instruction takes 1µs to execute. ...". The values have to be fixed somehow, so the authors did choose this one. The main point of this graphic is that the processor speed is not that important compared to the algorithm complexity (having a processor that is 100 times faster hardly helps solving bigger instances of TSP; but new algorithms and implementations may)

Comment: When someone points their finger at the moon, you should look at the moon, not at their finger

Comment: It's an *example* to demonstrate the running time difference between different complexities. It's (somewhat) like saying "John can sprint for 500 m, jog for 5 km and walk for 15 km" - the relation between sprinting, jogging and walking can still be understood despite knowing these numbers vary greatly from one person to the next.

Comment: It's not your question, but which book is this? Its definition of asymptotic time complexity "a rate of asymptotic growth of the time complexity f(n)" is quite hard to understand, if not downright wrong. Reading the wikipedia page for time complexity would serve you better.

Comment: This is the Zybook for Discrete Math

Answer (score 1):

ok i am coding for a long time so i can answer ur question the time complexity which u derive gives u idea about the time your program will take in the worst case and these  complexity are for large data not small data.Even if u perform a O(n**3) algorithm on a supercomputer and its corresponding O(n) complexity  algorithm on ur personal computer ,ur computer may finish much faster on large data. processor speed due matter but as does choice of algorithm.
hope it helps